# use max & sum at same time

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I have a situation where I have to sum & max a qty to handle multiple 
    entries per day.
    I have an input table in **cloudera hive** as :

```
    ----------------------------
    date1    |  date2    |  qty
    ----------------------------
    20180101 | 20180101 |   50
    ----------------------------
    20180101 | 20180101  |  15
    ----------------------------
    20180101 | 20180102  | 1
    ----------------------------
    20180101 | 20180103  | 3
    ----------------------------
    20180101 | 20180104  | 2
    ----------------------------
Final answer I need is :

    ----------------------------
    date1      |    qty
     ----------------------------
    20180101   |    56
    ----------------------------

Logic: For date1 cal 20180101   
= max(20180101 i.e date2) + sum ( all other date2)   
= max(50,15) + sum(1,3,2) 
= 56

**Will the lag / lead work here, can anyone help me with a hint of the 
solution? 

Thanks in advance.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query and check

```
select
date1,
Sum(qty_new)
from
(select date1, date2, max(qty) qty_new from 
table group by date1, date2) a
group by date1
```